# Batch For loop returns incorrect files using multiple question mark as wild cards

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have tried to get a batch script to iterate through a specific type of filename in a folder.  I do not want it to touch similarly named files that exceed a certain length or format.  Each time I run, the script returns too many files that do not match the filename structure

Files in folder:

```
ABC_4567.JPG
ABC_DoNotWantThisFileToBeProcessed_NoThanks_4876.JPG
```

Tried 1:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%f in (ABC_????.JPG) do (
        ECHO Processing file: %%~nxf
    )
```

Tried 2:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%f in (????????.JPG) do (
        ECHO Processing file: %%~nxf
    )
```

Returns this:

```
Processing file: ABC_4567.JPG
Processing file: ABC_DoNotWantThisFileToBeProcessed_NoThanks_4876.JPG
```

How can I solve this and return only the file of **shorter length** or that has the structure **ABC_####.JPG**

Thanks for saving my hair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for %%f in (ABC_????.JPG) do IF "%%~snxf" equ "%%~nxf" (
        ECHO Processing file: %%~nxf
    )

for %%f in (????????.JPG) do IF "%%~snxf" equ "%%~nxf" (
        ECHO Processing file: %%~nxf
    )

for /f %%f in ('dir /b /a-d abc_????.JPG') do IF "%%~snxf" equ "%%~nxf" (
        ECHO Processing file: %%~nxf
    )

for /f %%f in ('dir /b /a-d ????????.JPG') do IF "%%~snxf" equ "%%~nxf" (
        ECHO Processing file: %%~nxf
    )
```

By default, all files that do not comply with the 8.3 filename format are assigned an 8.3 name for compatibility with ancient software. You can see this by executing `dir /x`.

So, simply compare the name with its short version - no match, has two names, one long, one short. match, has one name...

Comment: Thanks for the teach. Had no idea 8.3 short file names were being used.  ABC_Do~1.JPG   Oops.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way, and that is to use the built in `where.exe` utility instead. This utility understands `?` to be one character, and it does not include 8.3 filenames either.

This example will iterate the current directory `"."`, for file names beginning with the case insensitive string `ABC_`, followed by exactly four characters, followed by the case insensitive extension `.JPG`.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('
    "(Set PATHEXT=) & where.exe /F ".":"ABC_????.JPG" 2>NUL"
') Do Echo Processing file: %%G
Pause
```

If you are going to be using delayed expansion within your `Do` portion of your `For` loop, please consider only enabling it there, not for the entire script.

Comment: I like this method. Where is very useful, I’m unsure if it will be blocked across our network so I will try both.  Thanks!

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why it would be blocked; after all, all it does is locate files. Or I suppose I should say, I've never known it to be, because very few people used to using it or think about doing so!

Comment: I will be using it much more often.